# Multiple graphs in php loop

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I have a problem with **google charts**. I developed a web page with 5  (generated with php) and 5 ID for each :

```
echo "<div id = \"ID\"  style=\"display:none;\">"
```

I also have 5 json arrays with all the information. I show in each  the data in a table but I would like also show a graph with my data.
I tried to do in this way (but it doesn't work):

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$n;$i++){

     $jsonTable = json_encode(${'table'.$Result_array[$i][1]});

            $ID =  $Result_array[$i][1]; //ID for the div
            echo "<script  type=\"text/javascript\">
                        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

                // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());

                function drawChart() {

                  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
                      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(".$jsonTable.");
                      var options = {
                              title: 'Company Performance',
                              hAxis: {title: 'L value', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, gridlines:{count:10} },
                              vAxis: {
                                  title: \"I rms\", 

                                  maxValue:1.5,

                                gridlines:{count:10}
                              }

                            };


                      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                      // Do not forget to check your div ID
                      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('".$ID."'));
                     chart.draw(data, options);

                }
            }


            </script>";
}
```

If I use this code only for 1 table, works fine, but when I use a loop and try to generate multiple graphs, it doesn't work.
Anyone could help me? thanks!

P.S: Maybe I also have to explain that, first of all, I have a table with my 5 results, and when I click, I have a onclik function to unhide the appropiate . This works always (with graphs and without it) but never display the graphs....

Answer (score 0):

Where are the 5 `ids` you are looping through only one `id`

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('".$ID."'));
```

It should be like this

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('".$ID."_".$i"'));
```

and add the div like

```
echo "<div id = \"ID_0\"  style=\"display:none;\">"
echo "<div id = \"ID_1\"  style=\"display:none;\">"
echo "<div id = \"ID_2\"  style=\"display:none;\">"
echo "<div id = \"ID_3\"  style=\"display:none;\">"
echo "<div id = \"ID_4\"  style=\"display:none;\">"
```

Comment: But I have the following line at the begining: $ID = $Result_array[$i][1];
In each iteration $Result_array[$i][1] is a different value

Comment: Maybe I also have to explain that, first of all, I have a table with my 5 results, and when I click, I have a onclik function to unhide the appropiate <div>. This works always (with graphs and without it) but never display the graphs....